# Add diff of images into one image (Linux/Python)

Tags: python, linux, image, image-processing, opencsv

I'm looking for a way to blend only the differences of images into one image. I'm looking for a linux command or a way to achieve this with python.

Example:
Source images:

[image]
[image]
[image]

The result should be:

[image]

Another usecase:
http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-h3yuVc0hyvc/ToqQDE0Bf4I/AAAAAAAAGj0/HON-gM_9PhU/s1600/JayBumpOllieStichedFinishedRS.jpg

Thanks!!

Vince

Comment: Maybe this could help you? 
https://github.com/derv82/imgblend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not exactly what I asked, but it does the job good enough for my needs:

```
convert 1.jpg 2.jpg 3.jpg -evaluate-sequence max evalresult.png
```

With the example image with the clouds it doesn't work really good (because the clouds are white), but in another context it is great (when the differences are brighter than the background)

[image]

Comment: If you are happy to use **ImageMagick** rather than the **Python** you tagged with, you may get on better with `convert [12].jpg -compose DarkenIntensity -composite 3.jpg -composite result.png`

Answer (score 1):

It would make sense to start from the image that contains background only and compare each frame with it. The background can be computed as median over the whole sequence. If we assume that background median image was a0.jpg and following three frames with 3 dots would be a1.jpg, a2.jpg and a3.jpg, then merging them together can be done using compare_images function of the scikit-image and modifying the values only at those pixels where the change was encountered. Note that due to compression there is a tolerance threshold (*th*) set to 0.1. You can play with that value (0,1) for more or less sensitivity.
Following script should to something like that:

```
import skimage.io as io 
from skimage.util import compare_images
import numpy as np

im0 = io.imread('a0.jpg') # median of source images
im1 = io.imread('a1.jpg') # source image 1
im2 = io.imread('a2.jpg') # source image 2
im3 = io.imread('a3.jpg') # source image 3

im_all = np.copy(im0)
th = 0.1

# d = np.max(np.abs(im2 - im0), -1)
d = compare_images(im1, im0, method='diff')
d= np.max(np.abs(d), -1)
im_all[d>th] = im1[d>th]
io.imsave("d1.jpg", d>th)

d = compare_images(im2, im0, method='diff')
d= np.max(np.abs(d), -1)
im_all[d>th] = im2[d>th]
io.imsave("d2.jpg", d>th)

d = compare_images(im3, im0, method='diff')
d= np.max(np.abs(d), -1)
im_all[d>th] = im3[d>th]
io.imsave("d3.jpg", d>th)

io.imsave("im_all.jpg", im_all)
```

[image: img_all.jpg]